# Classifier 'LayoutManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my code
package com.example.newsshare

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

}
```

i am new to kotlin and android development if anyone know how to solve this please help

i looked for solution which says it should be in abstract class but i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a reference to an instance of `RecyclerView` (an actual `RecyclerView` object). Here's one way you can do it (assuming you have a `RecyclerView` in `layout_activity_main` with an ID called `recycler`):

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler)
```

Now you can mess with its `layoutManager` property, and set a value on it:

```
// using the RecyclerView instance we just declared and assigned
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
```

**Note the case** - it's `layoutManager` **not** `LayoutManager`. Case matters in Kotlin (and Java), and [by convention](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#naming_2) properties and variables and functions start with *lowercase* letters (*camelCase* specifically). Class names start with *uppercase* letters (*Pascal case*). So when you do this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager
```

you're really referring to the [`LayoutManager` **class** nested in the `RecyclerView` **class**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager), not the `layoutManager` *property* of an actual `RecyclerView` object.

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the recycler view you (probably) have created within your activity / fragment, that's why you are not able to set a layout manager.

You need to create a reference to your recycler view either using viewBinding (or databinding) or findViewById(R.id.YOUR_RECYLCER_VIEW_ID)

you may find a full implementation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview-in-kotlin/)